# Entity Framework Code First Migrations and Pulling commits from Repository

Tags: git, entity-framework, bitbucket, entity-framework-migrations

I would like to learn what is the best approach on pulling commits from a repository affecting the Database (with newly added migrations).
After I pull those commits should I only update my database with the added migrations or should I make sure that the order of the migrations corresponds exactly to the order provided in the commits?
In my case I have to pull 2 new migrations, meanwhile I have already made some changes on my database as well:

Current Database:
-MigrationA
-MigrationBCurrentDatabase

Database in the commits:
-MigrationA
-MigrationBCommits
-MigrationCCommits

Result?
-MigrationA
-MigrationBCurrentDatabase
-MigrationBCommits
-MigrationCCommits

Or should it be:
-MigrationA
-MigrationBCommits
-MigrationCCommits
-MigrationBCurrentDatabase

My question is, does the order matter, or can I add migrations at any point as long as I only have to update my Database?

Comment: For single developer, no issues because EF will only apply the  missing migrations in order. What matters is merge conflicts with multiple team members. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481501(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Generally speaking, migrations must be run in the correct order. Imagine migration A that creates a table, and migration B that adds a column to that table. B cannot run before A.